# how to create a column with a logical value if two values match a certain condition in R?

Tags: r

I have the following data frame. of names, and the pay groups they belong to and whether or not they completed the program.

```
names<-c('A','B','C','D')
pay.group <-c('paying','non-paying','non-paying','paying')
status<-c('completed','completed','terminated','terminated')

pay.group<-as.factor(pay.group)
status<-as.factor(status)

df<-data.frame(names,pay.group,status)



names  pay.group     status
1     A     paying  completed
2     B non-paying  completed
3     C non-paying terminated
4     D     paying terminated
>
```

Basically I want to create a logical entry `TRUE` in a column called `df$paidandcomplete` if a particpant's pay group is `paying` and status in `completed`

How do I do this. Can I do it without using a loop?

Comment: Create a logical condition with `with(df, pay.group== 'paying' & status == 'completed')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using an `ifelse` statement

```
df$paidandcomplete <- ifelse(df$pay.group == "paying" & df$status == "completed",TRUE, FALSE)
```

Comment: Well, if the answer is `TRUE` or `FALSE`, you don't even need `ifelse`: `df$paidandcomplete <- df$pay.group == "paying" & df$status == "completed"` will suffice.

Comment: But this syntax would work for a host of other use cases as well. What if the OP wanted to add 1/0 flag

Comment: @SmitM Always avoid `ifelse` (if possible); in this case coerce to integer with `as.integer(...)` or using the unary operator `+(...)`.